# how do i check there is no matching in enhanced for loop?

Tags: java, foreach

I'm trying to update DB when there is no match in enhancing for loop.

what I'm trying is that
if there's no match between member `cardNo` and any `cardNo` from `cardList`,
I want to update member's `cardNo` to  `carNo` of `first[0]` Card from  `cardList`.

And I'm looking for a way to solve it 
with using enhanced for loop as my code 
and without using int i.

is there any other better way to do it?

here's my code

```
List<Map<String, Object>> cardList = cardLogic.getCardList();    
Map<String,Object> memberInfo = memberLogic.getMemberInfo(id);    
String memberCardNo = memberInfo.get("CardNo");    
if(cardList != null && !cardList .isEmpty()) {    
    int i= 0;    
    for(card : cardList){    
        i ++;    
        if(memberCardNo != null && !card.get("CardNO").equals(memberCardNo) && i == cardList.size()){    
            memberLogic.updateMemberInfo(id,cardList.get(0).get("CardNO"));    
        }    
    }     
}
```

Comment: Your code does not match your description. You need first to establish if there at least one match and only then update the member value. You still will need a temporary variable of some sort.

Comment: You also seem to be using big bags of `Map<String, Object>` instead of actual classes `Card` and `Member`, which are much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using stream(need up to java8)

```java
    if (memberCardNo != null && cardList != null) {
        if (cardList
            .stream()
            .allMatch(card -> !card.get("CardNO").equals(memberCardNo))) {
            memberLogic.updateMemberInfo(id, cardList.get(0).get("CardNO"));
        }
    }
```

using break label

```java
    BREAK_POINT:
    if (memberCardNo != null && cardList != null) {
        for (Map<String, Object> card : cardList) {
            if (card.get("CardNO").equals(memberCardNo)) {
                break BREAK_POINT;
            }
            memberLogic.updateMemberInfo(id, cardList.get(0).get("CardNO"));
        }
    }
```

Hope these are what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a for loop here, as you are checking if the `last item in cardList` is not equals to `memberCardNo` . You can check that directly.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> cardList = cardLogic.getCardList();
Map<String,Object> memberInfo = memberLogic.getMemberInfo(id);
String memberCardNo = memberInfo.get("CardNo");
if(cardList != null && !cardList .isEmpty()) {

    if(memberCardNo!= null && !cardList.get(cardList.size() - 1).get("CardNO").equals(memberCardNo)) {
        memberLogic.updateMemberInfo(id,cardList.get(0).get("CardNO"));
    }
}
```

Comment: if there is no loop, then how can i compare with all cardNos in cardList?

Comment: posted code has this condition ~~ memberCardNo != null && !card.get("CardNO").equals(memberCardNo) && i == cardList.size() ~~, so the condition will be TRUE only when all the conditions are TRUE, now look at ~~ i == cardList.size() ~~ , it checks if the current-card/i'th-card is the last card in cardList. Please correct me If I am wrong.